# Which is good practice to not activate the feature by default?

Tags: feature-activation

I have read about:-

1. Active Deployment Configuration : No Activation
2. Feature --> Activate on Default : False

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target of each setting is different:

**Active Deployment Configuration : No Activation**

This is a Visual Studio setting, determining if Visual Studio should activate all feature after you deploy through it.

**Feature --> Activate on Default : False**

This is a SharePoint setting, determining if SharePoint should activate the specific feature automatically. Only works for feature with scope Farm and WebApp. If true SharePoint activates the feature when solution is installed and if WebApp scope when a new WebApp is created

Comment: So when deploying via PowerShell, it looks for the Feature --> Activate on Default : False and not Active Deployment Configuration : No Activation? Is that right?

Comment: That's right when deploying through PowerShell, Central Admin, Code then it's only the ActivateOnDefault that's used